# woo-commerce change Item total as per quantity of item

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to create a woo-commerce plugin that will give a discount as per the quantity of product.

suppose, if price/roll is $1 and in one cartoon there are 36 rolls but cartoon price is $30 then when they add 36 rolls in qty price should be $30. Price for 2-5 cartoon and 6-9 cartoon is different but it in counting or in calculation we only consider the rolls, suppose 2-5 cartoon price is $0.9, if rolls are 100 then consider $0.9, 6-9 cartoon price is $0.8 and customer add 250 rolls then consider price $0.8.

Comment: Are you selling individual role as a product or group of product as a cartoon?

Comment: https://pluginrepublic.com/wordpress-plugins/woocommerce-fees-and-discounts/ This plugin might be help you better

Comment: @Ravi for group of products